# Проблема с проверкой задачи "Checker timeout error"

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия, списки, двусвязный-список

**Есть задача:**

В крупной компании по созданию программного обеспечения находится n серверов. Они соединяются сетью с помощью `m` проводов. Провод соединяет два сервера между собой.

Сервера `A` и `B` находятся в одной локальной сети, если сигнал от сервера `A` может по рабочим проводам дойти до сервера `B`, возможно проходя при этом через промежуточные сервера. Если сервер может соединиться только с собой, то считается, что он сам по себе представляет локальную сеть.

В датацентре компании появились грызуны, которые начали перегрызать провода. Пока ваш напарник поехал за отпугивателями грызунов, вам поручили посчитать полученный ущерб компании. Вам нужно ответить, сколько всего локальных сетей в компании возникало после выведения каждого провода из строя.

**Формат входных данных:**

В первой строке вводится целое число `n` (`2 ≤ n ≤ 3⋅10^5`) - количество серверов в компании.

Во второй строке вводится целое число `m` (`1 ≤m ≤ 3 ⋅10^5`) - количество проводов.

В следующих `m` строках вводятся пары различных чисел `a`, `b` (`1 ≤ a, b ≤ n`) номера серверов, которые соединяет `i`-ый провод.

В следующей строке вводится число `q` (`1 ≤ q ≤ m`) количество оборванных проводов.

В следующей строке вводится `q` различных чисел – номера оборванных кабелей. Все номера различны и идут в хронологическом порядке.

**Формат выходных данных:**

Выведите `q` чисел, количество различных локальных сетей после выведения из строя следующего провода.

**Примечание:**
Первый пример: после удаления первого провода все компьютеры все еще находятся в одной сети. После удаления второго провода, сеть разбивается на две части: компьютеры `1`, `3` и компьютер `2`.

**Примеры:**(моя программа примеры проходит)

**Sample Input 1:**

> ```
> 3
> 3
> 1 2
> 2 3
> 1 3
> 2
> 1 2
> ```

**Sample Output 1:**

> ```
> 1 2
> ```

**Sample Input 2:**

> ```
> 4
> 3
> 1 2
> 1 4
> 4 2
> 1
> 3
> ```

**Sample Output 2:**

> ```
> 2
> ```

После 5 (пяти) минут работы Чекера сайт выдаёт ошибку

> Checker timeout error

Не понимаю, в чём дело.

**Мой код (Python 3.4):**

```
def tupik(x): #   рекурсивная функция, которая вызывает себя до нахождения тупика локальной сети
    zamkrug = 0
    for i in range(0,len(proideno)): # проверяем просматривали ли мы этот сервер 
        if proideno[i]==x:
            zamkrug = 1
    if zamkrug == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        proideno.append(x) # записывает номер сервера в глобальный список, чтобы к нему не возвращаться
        a = 0
        i = 0
        while i < 2:
            j = 0
            while j < len(provod):
                Server = provod[j]
                if Server[i] == x:
                    a = tupik(Server[1-i])
                j += 1
            i += 1
        return 1 # возращает 1 при оконченом переборе проводов

n = int(input()) # начало тела главного метода
m = int(input())
provod = []
for i in range(0,m): # заполнение 2-мерного списка
    a,b = map(int,input().split()) # добавление номеров сервером связанных проводом i
    serv = [a , b] # вынужденная мера (по другому не работает)
    provod.append(serv)
q = int(input())
por = list(map(int, input().split())) # считываем список из q номеров порванных проводов (отсюда и название)

vivod = [] # список вывода
for l in range (0,q): 
    provod.pop(por[l]-l-1) # удаляем порванный провод (по хронологии)

    proideno = [] # список просмотренных функцией серверов
    locSeti = 0 # счётчик лок.сетей
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        povtor = 0
        for j in range(0, len(proideno)):
            if proideno[j] == i:
                povtor = 1
        if povtor == 0:
            if tupik(i) == 1:
                locSeti += 1
    vivod.append(locSeti) # добавляем кол-во лок. сетей в список вывода
print(*vivod)
```

**Новое решение (выдаёт ту же ошибку):**

```
def nalich(x):
    a = 0
    for i in range(0,len(set)):
        if set[i]==x:
            a = 1
    return a

def sosed(x):
    for j in range(0,len(provod)):
        serv=provod[j]
        if serv[0]==x:
            if nalich(serv[1])==0:
                set.append(serv[1])
        if serv[1]==x:
            if nalich(serv[0])==0:
                set.append(serv[0])
    return 1

n = int(input()) # начало тела главного метода
m = int(input())
provod = []
for i in range(0,m):
    a,b = map(int,input().split())
    serv = [a , b]
    provod.append(serv)
q = int(input())
por = list(map(int, input().split()))

vivod = []
for l in range (0,1):
    provod.pop(por[l]-l-1)
    set = []
    schetSet = 0
    a = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if nalich(i)==0:
            set.append(i)
            schetSet+=1
            a = sosed(i)
            for j in range(set.index(i)+1, len(set)):
                a = sosed(set[j])
    vivod.append(schetSet)
for l in range (1,q):
    a = provod[por[l] - l - 1][0]
    b = provod[por[l] - l - 1][1]
    provod.pop(por[l] - l - 1)

print(*vivod)
```

Comment: Ищите бесконечный цикл

Comment: его вроде и нет

Comment: рекурсия не бесконечна?

Comment: сделал новый код